# Retrieve SAML token from Dynamic CRM plugin

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, saml

I'm writing a plug-in to integrate Dynamic CRM 2016 with Sharepoint 2013 using Sharepoint api. I've followed [this](https://bingsoft.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/crm-online-to-sharepoint-online-integration-using-rest-and-adfs/) tutorial and everything worked out ok.

However, I don't want to hard code username and password but to use current user's credentials instead. So far I've been unable to extract the SAML token of currently logged in user from within my plug-in. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because it would imply a serious security issue. The token is only valid for authentication of the client. Hosts accepting the token are not allowed to use it to impersonate the client.

Answer (score 0):

With SAML you send a federatedID which is a username that has been agreed by both parties, you would add the federatedId within the NameId attribute.